# Find heap memory after process

Tags: linux, memory

How can we find heap memory of a process(in Linux) which we ran three days before. Will it be stored anywhere? by chance

Comment: Unless, you were logging memory usage statistics for some reason,  Linux does not record such information for later retrieval

Answer (score 0):

Once a process is gone, its memory is gone. You can't find its contents anymore.

Some traces of the process do remain: Linux, like most operating systems, wipes memory pages at allocation time, not at deallocation time. In other words, pages are wiped before the kernel hands them over to a process, not when it reclaims them from a process. So a forensic examination of the RAM (either by accessing `/dev/mem` (which of course requires root) or with direct hardware access) will reveal data from terminated processes.

However piecing these pages together (finding out how to arrange them together) is very difficult. Furthermore, three days later, it's likely that most of those pages have been reused already.

If you meant to find the *amount* of memory used by a now-terminated process, i.e. to find the heap consumption, that information is not logged anywhere by default or with common auditing frameworks. It isn't considered a particularly interesting information. Auditing frameworks are typically primarily concerned with security and accountability, not with performance tracking.